# Dependencies update after field renaming

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Recently we have database migration and everything was moved to Oracle platform and this opportunity was also used to modify the database structure. My task is to rename the majority of fields in all tables to make the naming corresponding with other databases to standardize the reporting process. I was provided with the list containing old and new column names which I used to create a group of ALTER TABLE queries to rename the relevant fields.

When I rename the fields all views, procedures and functions lose their dependencies.
I am working on Toad for Oracle but to be honest I am not literate with this application. I am not sure if it is possible to update all views, procedures etc. after field renaming but as far as I see Toad does not offer such an option.

Do you know how can I handle this task? Is it possible to do that with Toad or should I download other software?

Many thanks for your answers 

Comment: Just a minor comment, it's columns, not fields.

Comment: I spent too much time with MS Access :)

Comment: You can recompile all views and packages - but as far as I remember you cannot automatically apply column changes to all packages and views (though there is probably a search and replace feature for all open files - but this this would be a bit hacky)

Comment: Do you know any software with the function to update all dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

In My opinion than looking for in tool you can do it by your self. Say if you have all tables, views , and respective procedures & functions create statements  in a text files. Then you can make copy of this file with new column names then you can use some visual difference tool to compare and verify the your changes.  This way changes will  be in your control and it would be easy to roll back to go for ols change with your original file.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I already created a tool that converts the names but it is not a perfect solution. Sometimes the column name is the same as alias in SQL and as a result the alias may be renamed as well. My tool can handle such exceptions but there is still a chance that the conversion will be inaccurate. The second obstacle is the number of views, procedures and functions. In total I have +200 items that need to be corrected and reviewed which will be quite time-consuming.

Comment: Yes what you said is correct ,  we can't just find & replace old sting by new string. We need to do carefully replace with new column name for respective table only  if you have all 200+ objects in one single text file still its do able.